# How to create custom event id descriptions

Tags: windows

Can I create the appropriate descriptions for our custom events?

When we use our own event id's, we get the error or warnings in the Application Event Log, but they have this sort of detail ...

> The description for Event ID 20302 from source ... cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each [event source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has its own set of [event identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which are compiled using the message compiler, **mc**, in [message files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd996906(v=vs.85).aspx), with format:

```
MessageId=0x4
Severity=Error
Facility=System
SymbolicName=MSG_CMD_DELETE
Language=English
File %1 contains %2, which is in error.
.
```